# Missing hats on leaderboard

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winterbash-leaderboard

I have earned 12 hats on SuperUser.

However the leaderboard only show 9 of them:

[image]

There seems to be room on the right for more images, or we could have multiple rows of images.

Please can this be fixed?